# Show desktop in Applescript - help required

Tags: applescript

I'm looking for some help with the below please. I want to create a script to replicate windows' 'show desktop'. It's not working, can someone please help?

I'd then like to save it in my dock so I can click it as required to show/hide the desktop. Thanks.

```
property windows_hidden: "not set yet"
    if windows_hidden is false then
        activate application "Finder"
        tell application "System Events"
            set visible of processes where name is not "Finder" to false
        end tell
        tell application "Finder" to set collapsed of windows to true
        set windows_hidden to true
    else
        activate application "Finder"
        tell application "System Events"
            set visible of processes where name is not "Finder" to true
        end tell
        tell application "Finder" to set collapsed of windows to false
        set windows_hidden to false
    end if
```

Comment: macOS already has a 'Show Desktop' command. By default it's on F11 [or Fn F11, depending on how you have your F-keys set.]

Comment: This just shifts the windows to the side, I want to minimize/hide everything.

Comment: You can 'Hide Others' with Cmd/Opt/H, from any app, leaving you only to hide Finder windows, if that's what you need. [You can't hide the only app left showing, though you can hide other on an app with no window open, leaving only its menu bar visible..] This is not the same as minimising windows, which then don't reappear if you switch to that app.

Comment: Hi, can anyone help with this please?

Comment: Was my earlier comment not helpful - pointing out there are simpler ways to tackle the issue? I'm still not sure exactly what you're looking for… just some way to see the desktop picture in isolation; to enable Finder to come to the front with nothing else in the way; to be able to see Finder icons on the desktop?